# CSS Header Side By Side or repeated

Tags: html, css

i have a image header that isn't a vectorial image, so, when my page width exceeds my image width the page will remain with a blank space, as you can see in the picture:

[image]:

But i need that the image will fill this blank space, so, i've created a portion of image that i want to repeatand place side by side the existing image, but i don't know how to do it via CSS.

Any Help?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: try setting the image as background and use the `background-repeat` css

Comment: .header_container --> the first image
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 168px;
    background: url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.header_Repeater --> the image repeater
{
    margin-left: 0px;    
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 168px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/header_bg_repeat.jpg);
}

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

`background : url('image path') repeat-x ;`